# Is using the word "can" twice in the same sentence redundant?

Tags: word-usage

Take the following sentences for example:

> 1. Horror movies can be scary and can lead to nightmares.
> 2. Horror movies can be scary and lead to nightmares.

Is the second sentence simply a more concise version of the first, or does it change the meaning? I.e., does the first sentence suggest that horror movies can both be scary *and* lead to nightmares, while the second sentence suggests that horror movies can lead to nightmares as a direct result of them being scary? The difference may seem minute, but I think it's notable enough.

I am training to be a proofreader and struggling with editing for concision while not changing the original meaning of the text.

Comment: Leaving out the repeated verb implies the connection. Repeating it means you need it to separate the bits: Movies can be scary and can still be very entertaining.

Comment: @YosefBaskin That's what I thought! Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: If it were redundant we could never have had the Can-Can!

Comment: I can can-can and I can can vegetables, but I can't can-can and can vegetables.

Comment: There's the third reading: (1) 'Horror movies [can be scary] and [can lead to nightmares].' // (2) 'Horror movies can [be scary and lead to nightmares].' // (3) 'Horror movies [can be scary] and [they lead to nightmares].' (This because both base form and 3rd person plural simple present of 'lead' are _lead_.)

Comment: If I was copyediting, I'd reject the second sentence. Instead of "... and ...", one could say "..., which can ...", which is just as concise, and much clearer.

Comment: A prior manager of mine gave me the advise to never repeat a word in any sentence. However, this was in reference to business communication. Her reason was simply "It makes you appear smarter."

Comment: @DavidS Perhaps, but even better to distinguish between 'advise' and 'advice'.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime Anyone who can can-can can can, can they not?

Comment: “A canner can can anything he can can, but a canner can’t can a can, can he?”

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Both statements are fine, but there is a slight difference in nuance and emphasis.

If you repeat *can*, it can imply that you are considering the two negative impacts of horror movies separately, as two distinct, or independent consequences.

When you don't repeat *can*, it can imply that you are fusing the two consequences into one, as if the two go hand in hand, being interdependent.

However, this distinction may not be made in the author's mind, and the repetition or non-repetition of *can* may be a matter of mere stylistic choice. Some like to avoid repetition, whilst others prefer repetition for the rhythm and symmetry it gives to the sentence.

Comment: It's a slightly perverse interpretation, but OP's version 2 (*without* repeating ***can***) could be understood as *Horror movies can be scary and **are known to** lead to nightmares* (i.e. - the "tentativeness" of ***can*** only applies to the initial clause; the second one could be an outright assertion of *fact*).

Comment: It's not perverse if you flip the clauses - I am hungry and can be tempted by a nice sandwich.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would actually use "or" there to avoid that implication.

Comment: @trlkly: Hmm. I think that would just mark you out as a non-native Anglophone - it wouldn't meaningfully reduce any potential ambiguity.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think this might be a regional thing, because I would understand trlkly's usage and it wouldn't make me think they're not a native speaker.

Comment: @NonnyMoose: I'm not suggesting there's anything *wrong* with *Horror movies can be scary or lead to nightmares* - simply that I don't see how using ***or*** instead of ***and*** affects whether or not we assume the word ***can***  also applies to the text that follows it. Incidentally, I still have no idea *which* of those two possibilities applies if ***or*** is used. I'm simply saying that if trlkly is sure that using ***or*** removes that ambiguity, that suggests to me that he/she isn't a native Anglophone. I'd kinda like to know if you guys both agree on what that unambiguous meaning is!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm a native speaker.To me, using the "or" intuitively makes it where you cannot parse it as "Horror movies lead to nightmares."  f I had to guess why, I would say that  saying A or B makes B optional, and thus functions similarly to including the word "can." That said, I'd also argue that "or" makes implies they are  less connected than "and"  : "Horror movies can be scary and lead to nightmares" clearly implies that said nightmares are caused by being scary. "Horror movies can be scary and can lead to nightmares" is less connected, but still implies a relationship.

Comment: @trlkly: I don't really understand any of that. It never occurred to me that there could be a *third* interpretation - that it's the fact of the movies ***being scary*** that (can? does?) lead to nightmares. And I still don't know whether you're simply sticking with that third interpretation - and if not, which of the two possibilities ***I*** outlined applies for you if we replace ***and*** with ***or***. And if you can make a choice between those two, would NonnyMoose make the *same* choice?

Comment: I feel like you could even interpret "Horror movies can be scary or lead to nightmares" as an exclusive or - horror movies can be scary, but if not, then they will definitely lead to nightmares!

Answer (score 9):

Consider the below. Can you see how the second and third options have the same syntax but mean two very different things? For clarity, stick with the two *cans* in the first option.

> *Horror movies:
>  • can be scary
>  • can lead to nightmares*

> *Horror movies can:
>  • be scary
>  • lead to nightmares*

> *Horror movies: 
>  • can be scary
>  • lead to nightmares*

Comment: The third interpretation is not what a typical native speaker will understand the sentence to mean. To convey that meaning, you need to say: *Horror movies can be scary and **will** lead to nightmares.*

Comment: @PeterShor I think that's mainly because of the context, since most know that nightmares are related to being scared. Consider "Driving too fast can be scary and lead to accidents" -- I think many would interpret this in the third way.

Comment: @Barmar: "Driving too fast can be scary and lead to accidents" can only be interpreted in the first two ways. To interpret it in the third way, you would need to write "Driving too fast can be scary and **leads** to accidents."

Comment: Good point, I wasn't thinking about the conjugation.

Comment: I agree, it's ambiguous. And there's a third reading possible: In "Petrol can catch fire and cause burns", the two things petrol can do are not independent, there is an implication that the second effect will happen only if the first happens. A second "can" would suggest that petrol can cause burns even if it does not catch fire.

Comment: @Michael Kay - I think that's a great summation. It doesn't say that burning petrol always causes burns, in the same way that 'can be scary and lead to nightmares' doesn't say that scary movies always cause nightmares.  The conclusion of this reasoning is that omission of the second 'can' in the sentence is a stylistic choice that doesn't necessarily alter the meaning.

Comment: For what it's worth, with a bulleted list the implication, at least to me, is that you can apply the intro line to each bullet independently.  So the third option becomes "Horror movies can be scary.  [and] Horror movies lead to nightmares"

Comment: @PeterShor You're not wrong in the main but it's worth noting that you could verbally pause a bit and then emphasize the word _lead_ when saying this out loud. That would lead typical native speakers to parse it as intending always leading instead of possibly leading.